# How to Hide Navigation Bar When Using Full Screen Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, navigationbar

I am using a full-screen ‍`Dialog` to show `ExoPlayer` video in full screen mode. I am already using the following code in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` hosting the `Dialog` to hide the `Navigation Bar`.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hide the navigation bar in the beginning
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        //Set a system bar visibility change listener
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


    }
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the dialog opens the navigation bar appears and I cannot hide it.

```
private void openFullScreenDialog() {
    ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
    mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(PlaybackActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit));
    mExoPlayerFullScreen = true;
    mFullScreenDialog.show();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

The navigation bar appears no matter what options I use for the dialog or `setSystemUiVisibility()`.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: are you using dialog or talking about the same activity for which you gave the code?

Comment: Simply do this on show dialog hide/ translate Y some amount and Listen for dialog dismiss then show

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
        new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

            }
        }
);
```

Also override this method:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

The best solution is to use a DialogFragment

Show dialog

```
DialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DialogFragment.TAG);
```

Full screen

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.MainDialog) { //set the style, the best code here or with me, we do not change
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    };
    return dialog;
}
```

Style

```
<style name="MainDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide system bar `onWindowFocus` and show when `dismiss` the dialog

```
class FullScreenDialog(context: Context): Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if(hasFocus){
        hideSystemBars()
    }
}

private fun hideSystemBars() {
    window?.let {
        val windowInsetsController =
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(it.decorView) ?: return
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
}

override fun dismiss() {
    super.dismiss()
    showSystemBar()
}

private fun showSystemBar(){
    window?.let {
        val windowInsetsController =
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(it.decorView) ?: return
        windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mExoPlayerView.hideController()
```