# android: how to hide bottom buttons on dialog fullscreen

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to hide navigation buttons when a dialog is shown fullscreen.
I've manage to do it following this example: [Android fullscreen dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242851/android-fullscreen-dialog)

however, whenever i touch a button they appear again.

is there any  way to hide them properly?

[image: nav buttons to hide]

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Hide Navigation Bar When Using Full Screen Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003250/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-when-using-full-screen-dialog)

Comment: can you show full screen ?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet hides the navigation bar and status bar:

```
window.decorView.apply {
    // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
    // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
    // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
    // hide the navigation bar.
    systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
}
```

From https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation

Nonetheless for your case you need two things to happen.

- First, set `windowFullScreen` to true to allow the dialog to paint every pixel in the screen. (i.e. Use any FullScreen theme).
- Then, on you dialog, set the `systemUiVisibility` to `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`.

This will stop the navigationBar from ever showing until you reset the flags or dismiss the dialog.

The complete snippet:

```
class SomeActivity {

    fun showDialog() {
        FullScrenDialog()
            .apply {
                setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
            }
            .show(supportFragmentManager, "TAG")
    }

}


class FullScrenDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for dialog:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_logout);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        dialog.show();
```

Output is:

[image]

I hope it works for you.